# SO_KEEPALIVE behavior is enabled by default on Linux?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel, network-programming

I have a client/server application written in C using TCP sockets. I wanted to know dead server processes using SO_KEEPALIVE option enabled on client socket. I am using Linux.

I modified the default time from 2 hours to 10 minutes.

```
echo 600 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

I enabled SO_KEEPALIVE on client socket using setsockopt(). I intentionally killed(kill -9) the server process while it's sending data to client.

As expected, after 10 minutes timeout(plus additional time for probes), client socket got notified (read(scoket,...) returned zero).

However, to my surprise, even if I disable this option on client socket, it still gets notified after the specified timeout(read() returns zero).

Is this behavior by default enabled in Linux?

Also, I felt read() returning zero to be inappropriate, shouldn't read() return some error when the peer is dead?

Comment: When you kill a Linux process (or if the process crashes) all sockets are cleanly shut down and the connection with the peer is reset. If you want to test real dead clients you would have to firewall off all traffic from the server or unplug the cable or crash the kernel.

Comment: You can check by doing a getsockopt...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keepalive causes a connection reset. The only thing that causes `read()` to return zero is receiving a FIN. Ergo, you received a FIN, not a keepalive termination, and ergo this doesn't show that keepalive is enabled by default in Linux. It would be a violation of RFC 1122.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Let's say keepalive isn't enabled by default or with my changes. But I killed the server process. How could the client receive a FIN after a while?

Comment: Never mind. I killed the server process, but it has a sleep() call which seems to be spawned as another process.. and is still communicating with client. Thanks.

Comment: But there's something else... read() is also returning zero if I abruptly kill the server process(and associated child). Basically, client waits on a select() call to be notified when client socket is ready for reading.... when I kill the server, it immediately gets notified and read() returns zero. Why so? I killed the server abruptly, no close() or shutdown() is called in server, then who sent the FIN packet to client?

Comment: and... keepalive can also cause connection timeout

Comment: @ernesto `read()` returning zero means the client received a FIN, which means that the sender sent a FIN, which means that even if you abruptly killed your server the OS still send a FIN on its behalf.